# How to mock a member in the Class that you spy with powermockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, powermockito

How can I mock a member class in another class which has already been spied by PowerMockito.spy()?

```java
@Component
public class BoxFileDao {

    @Autowired
    private BoxFileService boxFileService;

    public void uploadFile() {
         .....
         boxFileService.uploadFile(user, credential);
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(BoxFileDao.class)
public class BoxFileDaoTest {
    @Test
    public void testUploadFile() {
        BoxFileDao mock = PowerMockito.spy(new BoxFileDao());
        (how do I get the boxFileService from mock?)
        mock.uploadFile();
        verify(boxFileService).uploadFile(user, credential);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@InjectMock` to inject the mocked `boxFileService` object in the real `boxFileDao` object. Your test class can be written something like

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class BoxFileDaoTest {

    @Mock
    private BoxFileService boxFileService;

    @InjectMocks
    private BoxFileDao boxFileDao;

    @Test
    public void testUploadFile() {
        boxFileDao.uploadFile();
        verify(boxFileService).uploadFile(user, credential);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no real need to define the `doNothing()` as this is the default behaviour on a mock.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you create your class under test `BoxFileDao` while injecting the mock for `boxFileService` into it. Afterwards you can create the spy on it.

For example:

```
BoxFileDao dao = new BoxFileDao();
dao.boxFileService = Mockito.mock(BoxFileService.class);

BoxFileDao spy = Mockito.spy(dao);
```

---

But the question would be why do you even want to do that? Is there a reason to spy on `BoxFileDao`, your class under test?